# Background remote actionable notification web service call not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    //call 2 web service here.
    [self jsonParser:jsonData];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

I called this method as follows

```
-(void)jsonParser:(NSData *)data
{  
    //[downloader downloadXMLContentsFromURL:actualURL withXML:encrypted];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actualURL]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *encodedXML = [encrypted urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, encodedXML];
    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
    {
         NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
    //Here call to other service not shown
}
```

I have enabled "Background Fetch" from capabilities also "Remote Notification"

Do i need to implement this Method?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler: (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

This works fine when app is active. But not working for App is in Background and Closed.same time when i open app it works fine.I want to run service in background when app close. how to fix this ?  any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable background fetch service and as following you need to set MinimumBackgroundFetchInterval.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return YES;
}
```

and Implement the method like this Public method implementation

```
-(void)jsonParser:(NSData *)data Completion: (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    //[downloader downloadXMLContentsFromURL:actualURL withXML:encrypted];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actualURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *encodedXML = [encrypted urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, encodedXML];
    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
    {
        NSError *localError = nil;
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&localError];
        if (localError != nil) {
            // handle your data here
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
            NSLog(@"New data was fetched.");
        }else{
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
            NSLog(@"Failed to fetch new data.");
        }
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
    //Here call to other service not shown
}
```

and Implement method like this

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];

    [self jsonParser:jsonData Completion:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){

        NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
        NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);
    }];
}
```

I hope this will help you and please check this link http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

Comment: Worked like charm..Thanks for answer.